# Installing rxtx bundle in my Raspberry

Tags: java, linux, raspberry-pi, osgi, rxtx

I want to install an rxtx bundle on my Raspberry Pi
the bundle will be running on KURA platform (Equinox is the OSGi container for Kura)

I installed the rxtx native library using:
sudo apt-get install librxtx-java

the .so was installed on the directory: /usr/lib/jni/

```
pi@raspberrypi /usr/lib/jni $ ls
librxtxI2C-2.2pre1.so       librxtxParallel.so     librxtxRS485-2.2pre1.so  librxtxSerial-2.2pre1.so
librxtxI2C.so               librxtxRaw-2.2pre1.so  librxtxRS485.so          librxtxSerial.so
librxtxParallel-2.2pre1.so  librxtxRaw.so
```

Then I followed this link to wrappe the rxtx library in a bundle
http://rxtx.qbang.org/wiki/index.php/Wrapping_RXTX_in_an_Eclipse_Plugin

I added to the bundle manifest this:

```
Bundle-NativeCode: /usr/lib/jni/librxtxSerial.so;osname="Linux";processor="armv6l"
```

cause my os type is linux, my architecture is ARM:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ cat /proc/sys/kernel/{ostype,osrelease,version}
Linux
3.18.11+
#781 PREEMPT Tue Apr 21 18:02:18 BST 2015

pi@raspberrypi ~ $ arch
armv6l
```

But still I can't install the bundle, I got this error:

```
!ENTRY  1 0 2015-06-19 10:19:40.982
!MESSAGE [IAgent][RemoteBundleAdminImpl@17f36b1] [startBundle] Bundle cannot be started: Error[code=-6000;message=Failed to start bundle: The bundle "RXTX_Bundle_1.0.0 [77]" could not be resolved. Reason: No match found for native code: /usr/lib/jni/librxtxSerial.so; processor=armv6l; osname=Linux;details=null]
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: The bundle "RXTX_Bundle_1.0.0 [77]" could not be resolved. Reason: No match found for native code: /usr/lib/jni/librxtxSerial.so; processor=armv6l; osname=Linux
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.getResolverError(AbstractBundle.java:1332)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.getResolutionFailureException(AbstractBundle.java:1316)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:323)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:300)
        at org.tigris.mtoolkit.iagent.internal.rpc.RemoteBundleAdminImpl.startBundle(RemoteBundleAdminImpl.java:230)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.tigris.mtoolkit.iagent.internal.pmp.InvocationThread.run(InvocationThread.java:54)
        at org.tigris.mtoolkit.iagent.internal.utils.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:179)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

What have I did wrong?
Thanks a lot for your help!

**Updates** 
after following @Jorge Martinez suggestion:
here is my updated line of the manifest:

```
Bundle-NativeCode: nativelib/librxtxSerial.so;osname="Linux";processor="armv6l"
```

here is the list of content of my rxtx bundle:
[image]

Comment: This page has a list of recommended processor values: http://www.osgi.org/Specifications/Reference  - it does not list armv61. It might be worth trying ARM_be or ARM_le instead?

Also, might be worth adding detail of how you tried to implement @Jorge Martinez suggestion - exact place within the jar and the updated Bundle-NativeCode line you used with.

Comment: I tryied ARM_be and ARM_le instead but nothing worked and I updated my question with the new configuration.

Answer (score 2):

Jorge's response is correct. Have you physically examined the bundle being created by Eclipse to confirm your nativelib directory is present? When exporting the bundle from Eclipse, you have to ensure you specify which folders and files are included in the build. This is done by opening the build.properties file and placing a check mark by the folder/files you wish to include.

Comment: Very good point. In fact looking closely at the screenshot, we can see that the `nativelib` directory is NOT inside the bundle `RXTXcomm.jar`!!

Answer (score 1):

You need to embed native libraries in your bundle (inside the jar or in a fragment).

I.e if you place your library here:

```
/this/is/yournative/package/librxtxSerial.so
```

you can use this manifest entry:

```
Bundle-NativeCode: this/is/yournative/package/librxtxSerial.so;osname="Linux";processor="armv6l"
```

Note that OSGi loads native libs by extracting them to a temporal folder and then loads them.

Comment: thanks for response. still not working :( I copied the native library that exist in /usr/lib/jni/librxtxSerial.so but without success, same error " No match found for native code"

Comment: Can you post the list the contents of your rxtx bundle?

Comment: Done, I eddited my question with the list of the contents of my rxtx bundle.

Comment: And did you change the `Bundle-NativeCode` header to point to `nativelib/librtxSerial.so` instead of `/usr/lib/jni/librxtxSerial.so`?

Comment: @NeilBartlett read my mind... Cannot think of what else may be failing

Comment: yes I did :( I triyed also as said @GregHNZ to use  ARM_be or ARM_le instead of armv61. Nothing worked :( .I am thinking of versions used, I used the rxtx release "2.1-7r2 (stable)" from this link:http://rxtx.qbang.org/wiki/index.php/Download and the native library I installed from the command line "sudo apt-get install librxtx-java" I dont think this can generate an issue. Thinking also if the KURA plateform is the one causing the issue but it is suppose to run equinox OSGI bundle. I really can't think of something else :s

Comment: Don't think it is related with KURA platform. It is more probable related with rxtx version match between Java and native libs. I recommend you to make a quick test with a simple Java application first to make sure everything works fine. Then it is just a matter of packaging into an OSGi module

Comment: Which Java version are you running on? A comment on [this page](https://blogs.oracle.com/jtc/entry/serial_port_communication_for_java) suggests that Java 7 is only able to distinguish the processor name as "arm" (no _be, _le or v61).

Answer (score 0):

Use this bundle [rxtx osgi](https://code.google.com/p/rxtx-osgi/). It should contain all you need.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for your responses!
The bundle is Active!

I used this link to get rxtx sources and to compile my native sources:
https://blogs.oracle.com/jtc/entry/java_serial_communications_revisited

and I updated the build.properties to include the native library.