# Using existing plug in project created from library in OSGi bundle for Kura

Tags: java, osgi, raspberry-pi2, xbee, kura

I am creating an OSGi bundle that will be executed under Kura (Target Platform: Kura Target Platform Equinox 3.8.1), on Raspberry Pi 2 model B.

The program should read data received on XBee and we want to use a library: https://github.com/andrewrapp/xbee-api

I created a new plugin project under [Eclipse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29), "Plug-in from existing JAR archive" from the JAR files from the site above.

I tried to set the new plug in as "Required Plug-ins" in the MANIFEST.FM → Dependencies of my project, but that didn't work (java.lang.ClassNotFoundException)

I tried setting up a new folder in my project containing the library, but it is not working.

A similar question was asked, but I don't understand the answers because they are not detailed enough (*[Using an external java library in OSGI bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30916055/using-an-external-java-library-in-osgi-bundle)*).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are only using the XBee API inside of your bundle, you would probably be ok just embedding the Jar file in your bundle. I think this process is pretty well outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340483/osgi-handling-3rd-party-jars-required-by-a-bundle).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making a non-OSGi JAR file OSGi-ready or embedding it, I propose to look for an OSGi ready ZigBee bundle.

I would start with the [zigbee4OSGi project](http://zb4osgi.aaloa.org/redmine/projects/zb4osgi/files). If this does not work well, then there is also a bundle from prosyst, but it does not seem to be free.

I found a [ZigBee binding at openhab](https://github.com/cdjackson/openhab2-addons/tree/zigbee/addons/binding/org.openhab.binding.zigbee). This might help you to set up your project. I think they are using the same library you look for.

Comment: Added information: Kura runs on RPi 2B
By reading the forum on the site you suggested, this isn't suited for rpi

Comment: AFAIK XBee != ZigBee. Xbee uses ZigBee only as a transport layer protocol, not application protocol. So a ZigBee library (which works up to application level) would not "*talk*" to XBee modules.